# Angular directive link method giving back element as object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mootools

This is my Angular code:

```
angular.module('player', [])
.directive('playButton', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
                    /* I want to get the element parameter bellow as HTMl, 
                    not an object with an element stored within.
                    I don't want to access the HTML element as element[0]*/
        link: function($scope, /* this parameter -> */ element, attr) {
            console.log(typeof(element));
            // element[0].addEvent('click', function() {
            //  console.log('Moo!');
            // });
        }
    }
})
```

What i want to achieve is getting the element parameter within the link method as html, so that i can manipulate it with MooTools. Is there any way to prevent the use of the [0] after the element variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.** Angular return a [jQlite](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) object. So, like jQuery, to select current html element you need to use `element[0]`. An alternative would be to assign a variable to `element[0]`.

```
var elm = element[0];

elm.addEvent('click', function() {
     console.log('Moo!');
 });
```

Comment: Is there some way of stopping angular from making it an jQlite object?

Comment: I believe if jquery is not loaded, then it will use the jqlite implementation. Otherwise, it uses jquery.